# Initialize QFile with auto

Tags: c++, qt

I'm adopting the modern style of using auto type deduction and I can't figure out why this:

```
auto file = QFile{filepath};
```

gives the following error:

> error C2280: 'QFile::QFile(const QFile &)': attempting to reference a
>   deleted function

Comment: Similar questions is here with the exact answer on your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9601821/qfileqfile-function-error-qfile-qfile-const-qfile-is-private

Comment: I found out this syntax is valid in C++17 as it introduced copy elision

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you wrote your code, you call the [QFile constructor](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfile.html#QFile-1), then its copy constructor. This last one is not defined in the QFile class, hence the compiler error message which told that this function has been deleted.

Therefore, you cannot really use auto here. But you can still initialize your QFile instance like:

```
QFile file{filepath};
// or
QFile file = {filepath};
```

Answer (score 0):

This function is already removed from your version of SDK or not marked as a public one anymore.